# Joint plot with regression line and classes by hue

Tags: seaborn, scatter-plot, jointplot

I have the following dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB'],
    'Sales': [ 200, 100, 400, 100, 300, 100, 200, 500], 
    'Price': [ 5, 3, 3, 6, 4, 7, 4, 1]})
```

I would like to plot the regression line of the overall data, but also the scatter points by hue (in this case by Product) in the same chart.

I can get the regression line by:

```
g = sns.jointplot(y='Sales', x='Price', data=df, kind='reg', scatter = False)
```

And I can get the scatter by:

```
g = sns.scatterplot(y='Sales', x='Price', data=df, hue='Product')
```

But there are two different charts. Anyway that I can combine the two commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell the scatterplot in which axis object you want to plot. Options for a seaborn jointplot are the main plot area `ax_joint` or the two minor plot areas `ax_marg_x` and `ax_marg_y`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB'],
    'Sales': [ 200, 100, 400, 100, 300, 100, 200, 500], 
    'Price': [ 5, 3, 3, 6, 4, 7, 4, 1]})

g = sns.jointplot(y='Sales', x='Price', data=df, kind='reg', scatter = False)

sns.scatterplot(y='Sales', x='Price', data=df, hue="Product", ax=g.ax_joint)

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

To extend on Mr. T's answer, you could also do something like this to keep the kde marginal plots of the jointplot:

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB'],
    'Sales': [ 200, 100, 400, 100, 300, 100, 200, 500],
    'Price': [ 5, 3, 3, 6, 4, 7, 4, 1]})

g = sns.jointplot(y='Sales', x='Price', data=df, hue="Product", alpha=0.5, xlim=(0.5,7.5), ylim=(-50, 550))
g1 = sns.regplot(y='Sales', x='Price', data=df, scatter=False, ax=g.ax_joint)
regline = g1.get_lines()[0]
regline.set_color('red')
regline.set_zorder(5)
plt.show()
```

[image]